# non-member function operator+(...) cannot have cv-qualifier

Tags: c++

I am currently writing a program to simulate gas in a box. But I have come across an issue with class operators. Unfortunately to make things annoying the class is called Vector, I know some won't like it being called this.

Vector.h

```
class Vector {
private:

double x;
double y;
double z;

public:

Vector & operator+=(const Vector & v){
    x += v.x;
    y += v.y;
    z += v.z;
    return *this;
}
```

I have editted the code above to make this problem clearer. I have left out the constructer etc as they dont effect the problem.

And for .cpp

Vector.cpp

```
Vector operator+(const Vector v) const{
Vector v2(*this);
v2+=v;
return v2;
}
```

And his yeilds error:

C:\Users\XXXXX\ClionProjects\XXXXX\YYYYY\Vector.cpp:95:34: error: non-member function 'Vector operator+(Vector)' cannot have cv-qualifier

C:\Users\XXXXX\ClionProjects\XXXXX\YYYYY\Vector.cpp: In function 'Vector operator+(Vector)':

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet I'd interpreted the question as a typo (just missing the declarator). Given that it's actually a different function entirely, that's clearly not the case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error tells you what's wrong. You made these non-member functions, but they should be member functions. The compiler detected the problem by your (correct) use of `const`, though the number of arguments is also lacking and that would be a further compilation error once the first was fixed.

Either you forgot to put these function definitions inside the `class Vector { ... };` area, or you forgot to write `Vector::` before `operator`.

Comment: `operator+ ` most certainly **should not** be a member function. I find this answer confusing.

Comment: @SergeyA: That's your opinion. It's not a fact. I am sticking to the _facts_.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet, no, you are not. *You made these non-member functions, but they should be member functions.* - this is your opinion as well (*should be*). And once we are to judge our opinions, you can rest assured, mine will find much more support than yours.

Comment: I am  inclined to agree with Sergey that your answer is unclear. But I do feel it is very close to the answer I need and maybe my interpretation is wrong. If you could make it clearer, even add some code if not to much trouble. I'd be very thankful.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès, it is a common idiom to implement `operator+` as a non-member function. There are several benefits to it: a. You can define operator+ which takes different types, both on left and right hand side. b. You can use move semantics for it's arguments. c. You can generaly right simpler code.

Comment: @SergeyA: That was not my opinion but a recognition of the OP's intent (as shown by the use of `const`). But I do take your point.

Answer (score 2):

Only member functions can have `const` specifiers. Both your operators are non-member functions (because they are missing class name as part of their signature) and are not defined inside the class definition.

As a result, you have a compilation error.

To fix this error you need to translate `operator+` to a free function: remove it's declaration from your `Vector` class and change it's sigature to (the easiest form):

```
Vector operator+ (const Vector& lhs, const Vector& rhs);
```

There are certain reasons to use a different signature, and accept first argument by value, but this is way too deep for your level, so I suggest to stick to const reference for now.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the other inputs, Both have merit to them. I have found my own answer based off of The answer given by Barry @BarryTheHatchet. And other sources. 
To solve this problem I moved the definition within the header file in the public section, giving me:

```
 Vector & operator+=(const Vector & v){
    x += v.x;
    y += v.y;
    z += v.z;
    return *this;
}

Vector operator+(const Vector v) const {
    Vector VecPlus(*this);
    VecPlus.x += v.x;
    VecPlus.y += v.y;
    VecPlus.z += v.z;
    return VecPlus;
}
```

This was the result, I do hope it is a legitimate way to code it and not a shody way to do it but would lead to later problems. I've advanced in my project and it has raised none so far.

Comment: In the second function if you make the argument non-`const` then you can work on `v` directly and avoid creating `VecPlus`, which is currently an excess copy.